# Need a tool to get C++ Inheritance Hierarchy of existing project?

Tags: c++, documentation-generation

I am trying to understand WebKit (2 Million lines of C++ code). I want a tool which takes a class name as input and tell me the names of all classes which inherit from it.

For example, if I pass in "RenderObject" it should return RenderInline, RenderBox.

I am using Fedora 13 and for debugging purpose I am using QtCreator IDE.

Comment: QtCreator seems to be missing this functionality: http://www.ohloh.net/p/qt-creator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) to generate hierarchy graphs and class listings. The output is similar to javadoc's. [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) can be used with Doxygen to generate beautiful graphs, but is optional.

By the way, isn't there already a documentation for Webkit  ?

Comment: No there is no documentation for webkit, :-)

Answer (score 1):

Understand for C++
http://www.scitools.com/